# "Отобразить ощущения"

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексика

Будет ли правильной фраза: "Художнику удалось отобразить светлые, радостные ощущения от любования природой"?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Лучше, конечно, “отобразить чувства”, но и ощущения можно, ведь ощущения и есть чувства, хотя есть нюансы.Светлые ощущения при любовании природой - чувства в душе, а ощущения - восприятие органами чувств.

В этом смысле верное употребление вот в этом предложении: *Большая культурная волна модернизма отразила ощущение современной жизни в искусстве в виде резкого разрыва с прошлым.*

Comment: Людмила, а Вам не кажется, что "отобразить" стоит заменить на "передать"?

Comment: Стоит, но автор ведь нас не спрашивает, на что заменить.

Comment: Я понимаю, спасибо! Просто хотел понять, правильно мне кажется или нет, сам сомневался.

Comment: Спасибо Артем и Людмила! Эту фразу учитель русского языка у моего сына в 7 классе обозначила как глупую. Я засомневался и решил обсудить. Значит моей интуиции еще хватает))

Comment: Видимо, она хотела сказать не "глупая", а "тяжеловатая". В самом деле лучше бы смотрелось: "Художнику удалось передать светлые, радостные чувства (переживания, настроения ) при любовании природой"  Но для мальчика-семиклассника нормально, у него пока ощущения, а не чувства.